# Fetching custom fields in WordPress gutenberg via a getEntityRecords call

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to extend getEntityRecords a bit

I have custom Tax with Metadata that I need in a Block

I have added the data into the API call

```
wp-json/wp/v2/locations?per_page=100&orderby=name&order=asc&_fields=id%2Cname%2Cparent%2Clocation&_locale=user
```

returns

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Marriott's Cypress Harbour",
    "parent": 0,
    "location": "ORLANDO, FLORIDA"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ss",
    "parent": 0,
    "location": ""
  }
]
```

but when I call this with getEntityRecords
select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'locations', { per_page: -1} )

I get

```
[{id: 3, name: "Marriott's Cypress Harbour", parent: 0}, {id: 2, name: "ss", parent: 0}]
```

I tried to add the fields in the query

```
select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'locations', { per_page: -1, fields: ['id', 'name', 'location'] } )
```

How to get the extra data (location) I need into an object on the block?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I am looking to do this as well, but can't find ANY info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the custom field in functions.php (or your plugin) before it can be used in the REST API:

```
function add_custom_field() {
    register_rest_field( 'POST_TYPE',
        'FIELD_NAME',
        array(
            'get_callback'  => 'rest_get_post_field',
            'update_callback'   => null,
            'schema'            => null,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_field' );

function rest_get_post_field( $post, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_post_meta( $post[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
}
```

In this example, change the 'POST_TYPE' to 'locations' and change 'FIELD_NAME' to 'location'. After that, your location field should be directly accessible in the data returned from getEntityRecords()